# Custom annotation error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, annotations

I have an custom annotation set up in my mapview using below code. Problem is that the position of the annotation image is incorrect, it put's it a bit to the right of the actual location instead of spot on like when using the regular Pins.

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    if(annotationView)
        return annotationView;
    else
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                         reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"townhouse.png"]];
        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(writeSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Any help at all would be grateful!

/Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcus,

use the `centerOffset` property of MKAnnotationView to move your custom annotation view.

`annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(xOffset, yOffest);`